# Setting different Execution Strategies for different contexts in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a project that has many DBs.  I want to set a retry execution strategy for all of them but one.  One requires the use of transactions so it's not compatible.

The documentation says to set it in the DbConfiguration which is application wide and only supports one per application.  I can't see a way to set different execution strategies for different contexts.  Is it all or nothing or is there an other way to set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the workarounds detailed here: [Entity Framework Limitations with Retrying Execution Strategies (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn307226(v=vs.113).aspx)

Or one the techniques for overriding the DbConfiguration here or using a different DbConfiguration here: [Entity Framework Code-Based Configuration (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699)